Nginx[emerg] "map" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
This is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   30d;
    application/javascript     30d;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        expires $expires;
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
        root /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name api.example.in admin.example.in;

        #location /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /media {
                autoindex on;
                alias /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django/media/;
        }

        location /static {
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
                alias /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django/staticfiles;
        }

#        location /.well-known {
 #               alias /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django/well-known;
  #      }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
        #location /.wellness/assetlink.json {
         #       root /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django/static/;
       # }


        access_log /home/ubuntu/logs/ask_local_access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/logs/ask_local_error.log;

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}


server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        expires $expires;

        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        root /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name api.example.in admin.example.in; # managed by Certbot
        location  /media {
           autoindex on;
           alias  /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django/media;
        }
        location /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static {
                alias /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django/static;
        }
        location /.well-known {
                alias /home/ubuntu/ask-local-django/well-known;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }

        access_log /home/ubuntu/logs/ask_local_access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/logs/ask_local_error.log;


        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}


    #listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    #listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.asklokal.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.asklokal.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = admin.example.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = api.example.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

This is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}

My nginx configuration syntax looks ok
#sudo nginx -t

nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "api.example.in" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "admin.example.in" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

My nginx error logs shows
2024/04/16 15:22:21 [emerg] 3741#3741: "map" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
2024/04/16 15:30:40 [warn] 3777#3777: conflicting server name "api.example.in" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

And I am getting http response code of 500.
It started when I modified my server_name from example.com to aaa.com and then again modifying back to example.com. It is working previously without any issues.

How are you starting Nginx? I would expect the error log to be the same as nginx -t, unless you are staring Nguni with a -c.
